# ¿Cómo generar coordenadas al estilo Excel?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.x

La idea es poder generar a partir de un número `n` de filas y columnas `(n x n)` de la manera más óptima posible, una estructura tipo matriz con las típicas coordenadas de Excel. Por ejemplo, para `n = 3` la idea es generar algo así:

```
[('A1', 'B1', 'C1'), 
 ('A2', 'B2', 'C2'), 
 ('A3', 'B3', 'C3')]
```

Obviamente si se supera la cantidad de letras, hay que hacer coordenadas tipo `AA1, AA2, etc.`. Puede ser con python base o con algún otro paquete tipo `numpy`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Con Python base, encontré esta forma que no sé si es la más óptima pero si cumple con el requisito:

```
from string import ascii_uppercase
import itertools

def grilla(casilleros):

  def iter_all_ascii_uppercase():
      size = 1
      while True:
          for s in itertools.product(ascii_uppercase, repeat=size):
              yield "".join(s)
          size +=1

  letras = [l for l in itertools.islice(iter_all_ascii_uppercase(), casilleros)]
  numeros = [str(n) for n in range(1,casilleros+1)]

  coordenadas = ["{0}{1}".format(l,n) for l,n in itertools.product(letras, numeros)]
  return list(zip(*[coordenadas[x:x+casilleros] for x in range(0, len(coordenadas), casilleros)]))
```

Si por ejemplo queremos construir una grilla de 10 x 10, haríamos:

```
import pprint
pprint.pprint(grilla(10))
```

Ejemplo:

```
[('A1', 'B1', 'C1', 'D1', 'E1', 'F1', 'G1', 'H1', 'I1', 'J1'),
 ('A2', 'B2', 'C2', 'D2', 'E2', 'F2', 'G2', 'H2', 'I2', 'J2'),
 ('A3', 'B3', 'C3', 'D3', 'E3', 'F3', 'G3', 'H3', 'I3', 'J3'),
 ('A4', 'B4', 'C4', 'D4', 'E4', 'F4', 'G4', 'H4', 'I4', 'J4'),
 ('A5', 'B5', 'C5', 'D5', 'E5', 'F5', 'G5', 'H5', 'I5', 'J5'),
 ('A6', 'B6', 'C6', 'D6', 'E6', 'F6', 'G6', 'H6', 'I6', 'J6'),
 ('A7', 'B7', 'C7', 'D7', 'E7', 'F7', 'G7', 'H7', 'I7', 'J7'),
 ('A8', 'B8', 'C8', 'D8', 'E8', 'F8', 'G8', 'H8', 'I8', 'J8'),
 ('A9', 'B9', 'C9', 'D9', 'E9', 'F9', 'G9', 'H9', 'I9', 'J9'),
 ('A10', 'B10', 'C10', 'D10', 'E10', 'F10', 'G10', 'H10', 'I10', 'J10')]
```

Explicación:

- Con la función generadora `iter_all_ascii_uppercase` hacemos un producto cartesiano entre cada letra de `string.ascii_uppercase`
- con `itertools.islice` solo recuperamos las combinaciones de letras hasta el número de casilleros
- Armamos otra lista con números de 1 a `casilleros`
- Otro producto cartesiano combinando ambas listas
- Por último reordenamos la coordenadas para que se vean en el estilo excel, letras para las columnas, filas numéricas.